# Telegram api : How can I distinguish album or grouped photos? (in python)

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I'm downloading messages from a channel/group. Problem I'm facing is album photos, each photo in the group or album has its own unique photoID and messageID. I couldn't find any way to know if they are in one album or not.

Messages look like this

[image: 1]

I would liek to save them as one message in my json file as :

```
{

    {
        "messageId": 60,
        "text": "cats",
        "date": "2023-03-01T15:59:46",
        "sender_id": 123456789,
        "isMedia": true,
        "isAlbum": true,
        "photos" : ['cat1.jpg', 'cat2.jpg'] 
    }
}
```

Basically I would like to find out if the last messages (photos) are grouped if yes then save them as such.

P.S. Sorry for my english, and maybe misunderstanding some tools of stackoverflow, this is my first time asking question.

I checked their messagesIds, but unfortunately in telethon library it shows all messages have unique id, couldn't find any method to distinguish other than that.